# z sorting issue with triangles in 3d

Tags: javascript, sorting, graphics, 3d

We coded a spinning 3d shape in js. There's a flicker in the render of the top triangle, we think it's because the z sorting is not working correctly. How do we resolve this?

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/06cbtqge/5/).

Here's the z sorting code:

```
// z sorting

// dots_for_rendering.sort((a,b) => Math.sqrt((b.x)**2 + (b.y)**2) - Math.sqrt((a.x)**2 + (a.y)**2))

for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
  polygons[i].maxz = -Infinity;
  polygons[i].minz = Infinity;
  polygons[i].midz = 0;


for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].verticies.length; j++) {
  var z = rotated_verticies[polygons[i].verticies[j]].vector[2];
  if (z > polygons[i].maxz) {
    polygons[i].maxz = z;
  }
  if (z < polygons[i].minz) {
    polygons[i].minz = z;
  }
  polygons[i].midz += z;
}
polygons[i].midz /= polygons[i].verticies.length;

}

polygons.sort((a, b) => b.midz - a.midz)
// polygons.sort((a,b) => Math.max(b.maxz - a.minz, b.minz - a.maxz))


// polygons.sort((a,b) => {
//   if (a.minz < b.maxz) {
//     return 0;
//   }
//   if (b.minz < a.maxz) {
//     return -1;
//   }
//   return 0;
// })
```

Here's a code snippet:

```js
class Tensor {
  constructor(){
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    this.vector = input;
  }

  takeInput() {
    var a = true;
    for (var arg of arguments) {
      if (typeof arg !== "number"){
        a = false
      }
    }

     if (a && arguments[2] !== true){
       return new Array(...arguments);
     }
     else {
       if (arguments[0] instanceof Tensor){
         return arguments[0].vector;
       }
       else {
          if (typeof arguments[0] === "number" && typeof arguments[1] === "number" && arguments[2] === true) {
            var res = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0]; i++) {
              res.push(arguments[1]);
            }
            return res;
          }
       }
     }
  }

  // used for + - * /
  change(f, input){
    for (var i in this.vector) {
      this.vector[i] = f(this.vector[i], input[i]);
    }
    return this;
  }

  copy() {
    return new Tensor(...this.vector);
  }

  dimentions() {
    return this.vector.length;
  }

  //-----------

  len() {
    var s = 0;
    for (var dim of this.vector) {
      s += dim ** 2;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(s);
  }

  norm() {
    return this.div(this.dimentions(), this.len(), true)
  }

  add() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x + y, input);
  }

  sub() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x - y, input);
  }

  mult() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x * y, input);
  }

  div() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x / y, input);
  }

  dot() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    var res = 0;
    for (var i in this.vector) {
      res += this.vector[i] * input[i]
    }
    return res;
  }

  rotate() {
    // WARNING: only for 3D currently!!!
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);

    var [x, y, z] = this.vector;

    // rotate Z
    var t_x = x * Math.cos(input[2]) - y * Math.sin(input[2])
    y = y * Math.cos(input[2]) + x * Math.sin(input[2])
    x = t_x

    // rotate X
    var t_y = y * Math.cos(input[0]) - z * Math.sin(input[0])
    z = z * Math.cos(input[0]) + y * Math.sin(input[0])
    y = t_y

    // rotate Y
    t_x = x * Math.cos(input[1]) + z * Math.sin(input[1])
    z = z * Math.cos(input[1]) - x * Math.sin(input[1])
    x = t_x

    this.vector = [x, y, z];

    return this;
  }
}



var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")


w = 300
h = 286

fov = 0.1
scale = 65;
offset = new Tensor(w / 2 - 5, h / 2 - 92, 0.1);
light = new Tensor(3.5, 0.5, 1).norm();

canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

var verticies = [];
verticies.push(new Tensor(0.5, 1, 0))
verticies.push(new Tensor(0.5, -1, 0))
verticies.push(new Tensor(-1, 0, 0))
verticies.push(new Tensor(0, 0, 2))


var polygons = [];
polygons.push({
  verticies: [0, 3, 1],
  color: 'red',
  nf: 1
});
polygons.push({
  verticies: [2, 3, 0],
  color: 'blue',
  nf: 1
});
polygons.push({
  verticies: [2, 3, 1],
  color: 'green',
  nf: -1
});
polygons.push({
  verticies: [0, 1, 2],
  color: 'yellow',
  nf: -1
});


for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
  polygons[i].id = i;
}

theta = new Tensor(1.5 * Math.PI, 0, 1.5 * Math.PI);

function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);


  rotated_verticies = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < verticies.length; i++) {
    rotated_verticies.push(verticies[i].copy().rotate(theta));
  }

  // z sorting

  // dots_for_rendering.sort((a,b) => Math.sqrt((b.x)**2 + (b.y)**2) - Math.sqrt((a.x)**2 + (a.y)**2))

  for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    polygons[i].maxz = -Infinity;
    polygons[i].minz = Infinity;
    polygons[i].midz = 0;


    for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].verticies.length; j++) {
      var z = rotated_verticies[polygons[i].verticies[j]].vector[2];
      // z += 1 * (Math.random() * 2 - 1)
      if (z > polygons[i].maxz) {
        polygons[i].maxz = z;
      }
      if (z < polygons[i].minz) {
        polygons[i].minz = z;
      }
      polygons[i].midz += z;
    }
    polygons[i].midz /= polygons[i].verticies.length;

  }

  polygons.sort((a, b) => b.midz - a.midz)
  // polygons.sort((a,b) => Math.max(b.maxz - a.minz, b.minz - a.maxz))


  // polygons.sort((a,b) => {
  //   if (a.minz < b.maxz) {
  //     return 0;
  //   }
  //   if (b.minz < a.maxz) {
  //     return -1;
  //   }
  //   return 0;
  // })




  for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    var polygon_2 = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].verticies.length; j++) {
      var v = rotated_verticies[polygons[i].verticies[j]]
      polygon_2.push(v.vector);
    }

    var norm = getNormal(polygon_2, polygons[i].nf);
    // var rotated_light = light.copy().rotate(theta);
    var brightness = Math.max(0, norm.dot(light))

    //ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(31, "+100+"%, "+(Math.min(9.0*brightness + 40, 100))+"%)";
    ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(190, "+100+"%, "+(Math.min(9.0*brightness + 40, 100))+"%)";
    // ctx.fillStyle = polygons[i].color
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].verticies.length; j++) {
      var vertex = rotated_verticies[polygons[i].verticies[j]].copy();
      vertex.mult(scale, scale, 1);
      vertex.add(offset);
      var n = 1 + vertex.vector[2] * fov;
      vertex.div(n, n, 1)

      // console.log(vertex.vector)
      if (j == 0) {
        ctx.moveTo(vertex.vector[0], vertex.vector[1]);
      } else {
        ctx.lineTo(vertex.vector[0], vertex.vector[1]);
      }
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill()
    // ctx.stroke()

    polygons[i].mid = new Tensor(3, 0, true);

    for (var k = 0; k < polygons[i].verticies.length; k++) {
      var vertex = rotated_verticies[polygons[i].verticies[k]].copy();

      vertex.mult(scale, scale, 1);
      vertex.add(offset);


      var n = 1 + vertex.vector[2] * fov;
      vertex.div(n, n, 1)

      polygons[i].mid.add(vertex);
    }

    polygons[i].mid.div(3, polygons[i].verticies.length, true);



    ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    ctx.font = '50px serif';

    // ctx.fillText(polygons[i].id + ", " + polygons[i].nf, polygons[i].mid.vector[0], polygons[i].mid.vector[1])
  }



  // theta.add(theta.vector[0] + (0.01*mouseY - theta.vector[0]) * 0.1, 0, theta.vector[2] + (-0.01*mouseX - theta.vector[2]) * 0.1)

  theta.add(0, -0.0375, 0);

  // fov = (mouseX - w/2) * 0.001
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();

// setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60)


function getNormal(polygon, nf) {

  var Ax = polygon[1][0] - polygon[0][0];
  var Ay = polygon[1][1] - polygon[0][1];
  var Az = polygon[1][2] - polygon[0][2];

  var Bx = polygon[2][0] - polygon[0][0];
  var By = polygon[2][1] - polygon[0][1];
  var Bz = polygon[2][2] - polygon[0][2];


  var Nx = Ay * Bz - Az * By
  var Ny = Az * Bx - Ax * Bz
  var Nz = Ax * By - Ay * Bx

  return new Tensor(nf * Nx, nf * Ny, nf * Nz);
}

function len(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0]) ** 2 + (p2[1] - p1[1]) ** 2 + (p2[2] - p1[2]) ** 2);
}



mouseX = 0
mouseY = 0

onmousemove = (e) => {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name=”ad.size” content=”width=300,height=600”>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>...</title>

</head>
<body>

   <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="238"></canvas>



</body>

</html>
```

** Edit:

Ok, we've significantly edited the code, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/mkwndoch/1/), and the following code snippet below. It's still not working correctly, we think it's something to do with the first line of this piece of code, any ideas?

```
    if (polygons[i].mid.copy().sub(camera).dot(norm) < 0) {
  var pathelem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  pathelem.setAttribute("d", path);
  pathelem.setAttribute("fill", "hsl(31, "+100+"%, "+(Math.min(9.0*brightness + 40, 100))+"%)");
  svg.appendChild(pathelem);
}
```

```js
class Tensor {
  constructor(){
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    this.vector = input;
  }

  takeInput() {
    var a = true;
    for (var arg of arguments) {
      if (typeof arg !== "number"){
        a = false
      }
    }

     if (a && arguments[2] !== true){
       return new Array(...arguments);
     }
     else {
       if (arguments[0] instanceof Tensor){
         return arguments[0].vector;
       }
       else {
          if (typeof arguments[0] === "number" && typeof arguments[1] === "number" && arguments[2] === true) {
            var res = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0]; i++) {
              res.push(arguments[1]);
            }
            return res;
          }
       }
     }
  }

  // used for + - * /
  change(f, input){
    for (var i in this.vector) {
      this.vector[i] = f(this.vector[i], input[i]);
    }
    return this;
  }

  copy() {
    return new Tensor(...this.vector);
  }

  dimentions() {
    return this.vector.length;
  }

  //-----------

  len() {
    var s = 0;
    for (var dim of this.vector) {
      s += dim ** 2;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(s);
  }

  norm() {
    return this.div(this.dimentions(), this.len(), true)
  }

  add() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x + y, input);
  }

  sub() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x - y, input);
  }

  mult() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x * y, input);
  }

  div() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    return this.change((x, y) => x / y, input);
  }

  dot() {
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);
    var res = 0;
    for (var i in this.vector) {
      res += this.vector[i] * input[i]
    }
    return res;
  }

  rotate() {
    // WARNING: only for 3D currently!!!
    var input = this.takeInput(...arguments);

    var [x, y, z] = this.vector;

    // rotate Z
    var t_x = x * Math.cos(input[2]) - y * Math.sin(input[2])
    y = y * Math.cos(input[2]) + x * Math.sin(input[2])
    x = t_x

    // rotate X
    var t_y = y * Math.cos(input[0]) - z * Math.sin(input[0])
    z = z * Math.cos(input[0]) + y * Math.sin(input[0])
    y = t_y

    // rotate Y
    t_x = x * Math.cos(input[1]) + z * Math.sin(input[1])
    z = z * Math.cos(input[1]) - x * Math.sin(input[1])
    x = t_x

    this.vector = [x, y, z];

    return this;
  }
}


var svg = document.getElementById('svg')


w = 300
h = 286

fov = 0.1
scale = 65;
camera = new Tensor(-w / 2 + 5, -h / 2 + 92, 0.1);
light = new Tensor(3.5, 0.5, 1).norm();

svg.setAttribute('width', w);
svg.setAttribute('height', h);

var vertices = [
  new Tensor(0.5, 1, 0),
  new Tensor(0.5, -1, 0),
  new Tensor(-1, 0, 0),
  new Tensor(0, 0, 2)
];

var polygons = [];
polygons.push({
  vertices: [0, 3, 1],
  color: 'red',
  nf: 1
});
polygons.push({
  vertices: [2, 3, 0],
  color: 'blue',
  nf: 1
});
polygons.push({
  vertices: [2, 3, 1],
  color: 'green',
  nf: -1
});
polygons.push({
  vertices: [0, 1, 2],
  color: 'yellow',
  nf: 1
});


for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
  polygons[i].id = i;
}

theta = new Tensor(1.5 * Math.PI, 0, 1.5 * Math.PI);

function loop() {
  // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  svg.innerHTML = "";


  rotated_vertices = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    rotated_vertices.push(vertices[i].copy().rotate(theta));
  }

  // z sorting

  // dots_for_rendering.sort((a,b) => Math.sqrt((b.x)**2 + (b.y)**2) - Math.sqrt((a.x)**2 + (a.y)**2))

  for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    polygons[i].maxz = -Infinity;
    polygons[i].minz = Infinity;
    polygons[i].midz = 0;


    for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].vertices.length; j++) {
      var z = rotated_vertices[polygons[i].vertices[j]].vector[2];
      // z += 1 * (Math.random() * 2 - 1)
      if (z > polygons[i].maxz) {
        polygons[i].maxz = z;
      }
      if (z < polygons[i].minz) {
        polygons[i].minz = z;
      }
      polygons[i].midz += z;
    }
    polygons[i].midz /= polygons[i].vertices.length;


    polygons[i].mid = new Tensor(3, 0, true);

    for (var k = 0; k < polygons[i].vertices.length; k++) {
      var vertex = rotated_vertices[polygons[i].vertices[k]].copy();

      vertex.mult(scale, scale, 1);
      vertex.sub(camera);


      var n = 1 + vertex.vector[2] * fov;
      vertex.div(n, n, 1)

      polygons[i].mid.add(vertex);
    }

    polygons[i].mid.div(3, polygons[i].vertices.length, true);

  }

  polygons.sort((a, b) => b.midz - a.midz)
  // polygons.sort((a,b) => Math.max(b.maxz - a.minz, b.minz - a.maxz))


  // polygons.sort((a,b) => {
  //   if (a.minz < b.maxz) {
  //     return 0;
  //   }
  //   if (b.minz < a.maxz) {
  //     return -1;
  //   }
  //   return 0;
  // })


  for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    var polygons_embedded_point_coords = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].vertices.length; j++) {
      var v = rotated_vertices[polygons[i].vertices[j]]
      polygons_embedded_point_coords.push(v.vector);
    }

    var norm = getNormal(polygons_embedded_point_coords, polygons[i].nf);
    // var rotated_light = light.copy().rotate(theta);
    var brightness = Math.max(0, norm.dot(light))

    // ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(31, "+100+"%, "+(Math.min(9.0*brightness + 40, 100))+"%)";
    // ctx.fillStyle = polygons[i].color
    // ctx.beginPath();

    var path = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].vertices.length; j++) {
      var vertex = rotated_vertices[polygons[i].vertices[j]].copy();
      vertex.mult(scale, scale, 1);
      vertex.sub(camera);
      var n = 1 + vertex.vector[2] * fov;
      vertex.div(n, n, 1)

      // console.log(vertex.vector)
      if (j == 0) {
        // ctx.moveTo(vertex.vector[0], vertex.vector[1]);
        path.push("M "+vertex.vector[0]+" "+vertex.vector[1]);
      } else {
        path.push("L "+vertex.vector[0]+" "+vertex.vector[1]);
        // ctx.lineTo(vertex.vector[0], vertex.vector[1]);
      }
    }


    // that should work
    if (polygons[i].mid.copy().sub(camera).dot(norm) < 0) {
      var pathelem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
      pathelem.setAttribute("d", path);
      pathelem.setAttribute("fill", "hsl(31, "+100+"%, "+(Math.min(9.0*brightness + 40, 100))+"%)");
      svg.appendChild(pathelem);
    }


    // ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    // ctx.font = '15px serif';
    //
    // ctx.fillText(polygons[i].id + ", " + polygons[i].nf, polygons[i].mid.vector[0], polygons[i].mid.vector[1])
  }


  // theta.add(theta.vector[0] + (0.01*mouseY - theta.vector[0]) * 0.1, 0, theta.vector[2] + (-0.01*mouseX - theta.vector[2]) * 0.1)

  theta.add(0, -0.0375, 0);

  // fov = (mouseX - w/2) * 0.001
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();

// setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60)


function getNormal(vertices, nf) {

  var Ax = vertices[1][0] - vertices[0][0];
  var Ay = vertices[1][1] - vertices[0][1];
  var Az = vertices[1][2] - vertices[0][2];

  var Bx = vertices[2][0] - vertices[0][0];
  var By = vertices[2][1] - vertices[0][1];
  var Bz = vertices[2][2] - vertices[0][2];

  var Nx = Ay * Bz - Az * By
  var Ny = Az * Bx - Ax * Bz
  var Nz = Ax * By - Ay * Bx

  return new Tensor(nf * Nx, nf * Ny, nf * Nz);
}

function len(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt((p2[0] - p1[0]) ** 2 + (p2[1] - p1[1]) ** 2 + (p2[2] - p1[2]) ** 2);
}


mouseX = 0
mouseY = 0

onmousemove = (e) => {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="Tensor.js"></script>
  <script src="script-tensors-svg.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> -->
  <svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting by average Z just doesn't give you a reliable rendering order. Since your shape is convex, though, you don't need to sort at all.

Make sure the vertices of each triangle are sorted so that you can consistently get a surface normal that points outward.  Then, just don't render any triangles with normals that point *away* from the camera, i.e.:

```
if (vector_from_camera_to_poly_midpoint \dot poly_normal < 0) {
   //render the poly
}
```

Now you will only render the side of the object that is facing the camera -- none of the polygons will overlap, so you can render them in any order.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for that it looks like a solid strategy. I've updated the post above, and you can see the outcome in the new code snippet (it's missing a few surfaces). We think we're not quite implementing your suggestion correctly in the following line `if (polygons[i].mid.copy().sub(camera).dot(norm) < 0)`.  But we can't see where our incorrect logic is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok well, we got it working by just making sure the top triangle always stays on the top instead of letting it get sorted, which is basically what you suggested.